# Reducing list of pairs by summing repeating ones

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of pairs $\{\{a_1,A_1\},\ldots\{a_n,A_n\}\}$. Suppose $A_i=A_j$ for some $i\neq j$. Then I would like to eliminate both $\{a_i,A_i\}$ and $\{a_j,A_j\}$ from this list, and instead of them put $\{a_i+a_j,A_i\}$. How I can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a testing setup:

```
SeedRandom[1];
chars = RandomChoice[Alphabet[], 10]
nums = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 10]
myList = Transpose[{nums, chars}]
```

> ```
> {{4, "f"}, {3, "a"}, {3, "h"}, {7, "a"}, {6, "c"}, {5, "d"}, {4, 
>   "a"}, {1, "v"}, {5, "a"}, {7, "q"}}
> ```

---

First step is to `GatherBy` the last entry:

```
GatherBy[myList, Last]
```

> ```
> {{{4, "f"}}, {{3, "a"}, {7, "a"}, {4, "a"}, {5, "a"}}, {{3, 
>    "h"}}, {{6, "c"}}, {{5, "d"}}, {{1, "v"}}, {{7, "q"}}}
> ```

For each of these sublists, `Total` the first column and copy last entry of the first item as at least one item is guaranteed to be present in the sublist:

```
{Plus @@ #[[All, 1]], Last@First@#} & /@ GatherBy[myList, Last]
```

> ```
> {{4, "f"}, {19, "a"}, {3, "h"}, {6, "c"}, {5, "d"}, {1, "v"}, {7, 
>   "q"}}
> ```

Answer (score 8):

```
myList = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {4, "a"}};

KeyValueMap[
  {#2, #1}&,
  GroupBy[myList, Last -> First, Total]
]

(* Out: {{5, a}, {2, b}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, if I understood correctly:

```
myList = {{1, "a"}, {2, "b"}, {4, "a"}};
```

Now, just find where each `a`, and `b` are, and "add" them:

```
myReducedList = {{Total[#[[1]] & /@ Select[myList, #[[2]] == "a" &]], "a"},
 {Total[#[[1]] & /@ Select[myList, #[[2]] == "b" &]], "b"}}
(*{{5, "a"}, {2, "b"}}*)
```

Comment: It is not like that. For example take a list $((1,a),(2,b),(4,a))$. Then the result should be $((5,a),(2,b))$.

Comment: @mikis not sure I understand, but maybe my updated version works?